# Set shape / inlineshape as Decorative in Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, office365, vsto, accessibility

In Office 365 Microsoft introduced a new property for Shapes / InlineShapes (pictures): `Decorative`

I can manipulate it using `VBA` as demonstrated here, but *not* using `VSTO`, which is what I really need.

The value type is `Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState` and if set to msoTrue it enables the feature on the picture.

I've been able to toggle this feature easily using `VBA`, as demonstrated here (to try it, just insert an inline image in an empty document in `Microsoft Word 365`)

```
Sub ToggleDecorativePic()
    Dim pic As InlineShape
    Set pic = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1)
    pic.Decorative = Not pic.Decorative
End Sub
```

This will toggle the Decorative property of the first InLineShape in the active document.

[image: Before code executed]

[image: After code executed]

**But here's the actual problem:**

I need to do this from `VSTO` (`C#` or `VB.NET`), but the property `.Decorative` is not available in Intellisense, and even if I try forcing it by typecasting the `InlineShape` object to `Dynamic`, it just crashes when executing the code.

I'm using this Office Interop nuGet bundle to interact with Word:
`Bundle.Microsoft.Office.Interop` version `15.0.4569` dated `October 23rd 2018` so it should be up-to-date.
The bundle contains Interop ressources for Microsoft Excel, Outlook, PowerPoint and **Word**.

I also tried using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` but it's about two years old, so it obviously doesn't contain this new feature either.

I hope someone can help me in the right direction.

With the new EU laws regarding accessible documents, this is a ***critical feature*** when generating PDF documents using `Microsoft Word`.

Alternately: Is it possible to dynamically execute this as `VBA` somehow, from `VSTO`, without creating macros in the document etc.? I'm guessing no, at least not without enabling trust in the object model, which is just not a feasible option :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting problem, indeed. At first, I thought it could perhaps be solved by setting the reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` to the PIAs in the GAC rather than those installed by Visual Studio (which is the default source for a VSTO project) and by setting "embed interop types" to false. Both had no effect, however.

That left only the option of using `PInvoke`, which did work for me:

```
    Word.InlineShape ils = doc.InlineShapes[1];

    object oIls = ils;
    object isDec = oIls.GetType().InvokeMember("Decorative", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, oIls, null);

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Is the InlineShape marked as decorative: " + isDec.ToString());

    if ((int)isDec != -1)
    {
        object[] arg = new object[] { -1 };
        oIls.GetType().InvokeMember("Decorative", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, oIls, arg);
    }
```

Comment: Interesting approach, I would not have thought of that :-) It works, thanks a lot :-) I do hope it'll be officially available in IntelliSense soon anyway, but this is a nice fix until that day!